# In TFS, should I label or create a branch for a production release?

Tags: tfs, branch

When making a deployment to production, should I mark my code with a label or create a branch for the code that's in production?

Answer (score 19):

In TFS, I would have a Release branch with a label identifying the specific version being released to production.

Which would imply you have other branches may I suggest the following

- Three major branches: Main, Develop, & Release.
- One Hotfix branch for your current fire.
- 0 to N Major-Feature branches to contain the disruption of development.

#### Details

- Main Branch

  - Contains the latest stable builds
  - **Tag/Label** each release
- Develop Branch

  - Branched from the Main
  - Where most of the work is done
  - Merge back to Main before release
- Release Branch

  - Branched from one of the following:

    - The Develop branch
    - OR the Main branch (this may be better since it is "stable")
  - Bug fixes are done here
  - After fixes are tested and released,

    - merge to Develop branch
    - OR merge to Main branch and then forward integrate (FI - which is a merge from parent to child) to Develop
  - **Tag/Label** each release or bug fix
- Hotfix Branch

  - Branched from Main
  - Merged back into Main
  - Forward integrate merge to Develop
  - Used to allow Main to remain "stable"
- Major Feature Branches

  - Branched from Develop
  - Merged back into Develop
  - Used for major features that would possibly disrupt the regular development path

References:

- another stack overflow question: [when-to-use-a-tag-label-and-when-to-branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542029/when-to-use-a-tag-label-and-when-to-branch) especially Martin Woodward's answer
- [Source Control How To](http://www.ericsink.com/scm/source_control.html) by Eric Sink
- [A successful Git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/) by Vincent Driessen

  - This contains a very good graphic of a branching model

Comment: While this is some good information, I don't feel it actually answers the question that was asked.

Comment: @CodeMaverick Hard to judge, but it does seem to address the question in a roundabout way. In short, given his detail above, it would seem he is suggesting branching, and a particular practice of doing so.

Comment: @CodeMaverick I see your point. I will edit it to be a more succinct answer and relegate the rest to support info.

Comment: Doesnt the GIT branching model cause a baseless merge issue branching a release from develop and merging it back to develop and master?

Answer (score 3):

Ideally, both.

You probably want to have a *label* so that you know exactly what you delivered for a specific release.  However, you probably also want to create a *branch* so that you can perform minor bug fixing to what was released and create a new release.

Comment: See "[Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/)" for excellent advice and details on branching strategy.

Answer (score 1):

In practice, you could approach it in one of two ways:

- Have a continuous developmental timeline that gets branched for each of your production releases:

example:

```
 ------------------------->dev
     |      |      |
     |      |      |
     |      |      |
    v1.0   v2.0   v3.0
```

- Have your production releases "cascade" off of one another:

example:

```
---->v1.0---->v2.0---->v3.0
```

Ultimately, up to you in deciding what architecture to adopt, as long as it's consistent and makes sense to you.

Comment: One nice thing about option 1 is you don't "have" to create a build definition for each new version.  You deploy from the Main development branch and that's it.  As soon as it's built and deployed, tag (ie: create a new branch from) the new version so you can roll back to it if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of both. Here is how we do this internally for all projects.

We have structure with folder Branches and sub folder for each minor and major version. We also use labels that we set on individual sub folders so we can easily rebuild any specific version any time in the future.

```
$\Branches
    \2012.01
    \2012.02 (branched from 2012.01)
    \2012.03 (branched from 2012.02)
    \2013.01 (branched from 2012.03)
```

You can also check out [Visual Studio Team Foundation Server Branching and Merging Guide](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen both done, Labeling is more lightweight and to me easier. But, it has been pointed out that labels can be deleted rather easily. A branch protects against this by not actually being deleted unless "destroyed". The reason I prefer not use branches is I hate having to cloak them as I tend to do get latest from the root and don't want all those branches filling up my hard drive

For the record, since it was pointed out to me about label's being deleted I have removed permissions for Labeling from everyone but Admins and the build service accounts to help mitigate this.