# TFS 2012 - How to Differentiate "Done" vs "Deployed"?

Tags: tfs

How does your team differentiate TFS work items that are "done" (development/testing complete) vs. "deployed" (live in Production)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [In TFS, should I label or create a branch for a production release?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143331/in-tfs-should-i-label-or-create-a-branch-for-a-production-release)

Comment: Not really. Asking about state of TFS work items, not branching/merging of source code.

Answer (score 1):

My first option would be to use a [Tag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn132606.aspx) to mark this. You can query and filter through them.

Another option would be to customize the work item types with an additional field, but this route is a bit more complex.

Answer (score 0):

Change your Definition of Done to include: Deployed. Doing that you will have code working in production. If is needed more work, is not done.

But I guess you´re asking about how to have a new status. You can modify the workflow template to include this new state. In older versions of TFS you only can do that before to create the project, not in an started project. I don´t know in the latest version.

Comment: The problem with including deployed in the definition of done is: How can developers track what they have finished developing (items that haven't been deployed yet?)

Comment: Developers (or qa) just focus in their area is, in my opinion, one of the most blocking issues in agile. I think it´s better been focus as a team and been focus in deliver things. If you can reduce the amount of steps in your process, even better. For example, some people needs a peer review column, because the code is not develop with pair programing. Is needed a test column because the team has "qa" roles that don´t work with devs.  Know when development is finished is important because dev have to throw to the next group, qa. This is really waterfallish in my point of view. Too many silos.