# TFS Merging between two experimental branches without modifying main

Tags: tfs, branching-and-merging, branching-strategy

We have release branches that are branches off of main.

We also have experimental branches that are branched off of main.

We now have a feature in one experimental branch that we want to add to another experimental branch.

The problem is that we don't want to merge those changes into main yet because then it would go out in a release sooner than planned.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Baseless merge? Should experimental branches not be merged off of main?

Comment: Have you considered merging experimental A branch into your experimental B branch, or are there other features in A that you don't want to take across?

Comment: There are features I don't want taken across.

Comment: For future reference, features should be developed in their own branches to allow for testing in isolation and easier merges.

Answer (score 1):

If you only worried about the planned release, you could [use labels](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-labels-take-snapshot-your-files) as a workaround. The difference between label and release branch you can refer this question：[In TFS, should I label or create a branch for a production release?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15143331/in-tfs-should-i-label-or-create-a-branch-for-a-production-release)

As for should experimental branches be merged off of main or not, it's based on the useage of your experimental branch. If you branched what you needed from the main branch into an experimental branch. After some changes on experimental branch, you want to apply the changes to main, then you should merge back into main. If you fininshed the work and will work on another one, then you don't have to merge off of main and you could orphan this branch or delete it.

If you really want to perform this type of merge you can through something called a **baseless merge**. You could run it in UI with VS2012 and up or runs from the **tfs command prompt**:

```
Tf merge /baseless <<source path>> <<target path>> /recursive
```