# What is best practice when releasing a version so you can make updates to that version only later

Tags: tfs

I want to release a version of a project, and note this in TFS so I can come back later and make minor updates as needed.

What is the usual practice for this?  As far as I can tell, I should do a branch and note the version number.

Comment: I found this comprehensive guide to Branching and Merging here: http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/downloads/get/512036

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Branching by release is a common practice for many.  We currently branch every release for potential hotfixes.

You can also use labels to mark your source at time of release.  And you can branch from that later if needed.

This post has a good answer on the difference:
[When to use a Tag/Label and when to branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542029/when-to-use-a-tag-label-and-when-to-branch)

I also recomend you look over the ALM Rangers guide to [TFS Branching and Merging](https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/).
https://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/

Comment: Cool, It's a great resource.